# searching items from table using mysql like

Tags: mysql

```
String name = request. getParameter ("name");
String queryString ="SELECT * FROM empy WHERE name LIKE '%'"+sname+"''";
```

I am using this query to search textfiled entering values. But it displays an error message..

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'textfiled value''' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use the invalid variable 'sname' whereas you have declared the variable as 'name'
Try this

String queryString :

```
"SELECT * FROM empy WHERE name LIKE '%"+name+"'";
```

Also, if you can see the logs, see that the query generated is correct or not by hitting it directly on MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 String queryString ="SELECT * FROM empy WHERE name  LIKE '%" + name + "';
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra `'` from your query. It should be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM empy WHERE name LIKE '%MySname'
```

Try this: `"SELECT * FROM empy WHERE name LIKE '%" + sname + "'"`

Answer (score 0):

The variable name is `name` not `sname`. Also remove the `''`

```
String queryString ="SELECT * FROM empy WHERE name LIKE '%"+name+"'";
```